# Lightswitch - access Shell object from Application object

Tags: mef, visual-studio-lightswitch

Does anybody know, how Lightswitch's Application object can access shell object?

Application.Details.GetModel().Shell is type of - Microsoft.LightSwitch.Model.IShellDefinition {Microsoft.LightSwitch.Model.Storage.Shell}. But I need to access shell object, not its definition?

May MEF import/export is right way, but I don't know how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the wrong type of *shell*. That refers to *Shell extension type*, which is one of the LightSwitch extension types for customising it. A *Shell* handles the layout of all of the controls of the application uses to display itself.

You need to use the *AutomationFactory* (which is only available for **out-of-browser** applications) to access the type of *shell object* that you're wanting:

```
If (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable = True) Then
    Dim shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject(APPLICATION_ID)

    shell.ShellExecute()
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. I use application in browser. I need it for access my view model which my custom shell use. Finally I used MEF's Export attribute on this view model and then call VsExportProviderService.GetExport<MyViewModel>().Value from Lightswitch's Application class.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Do you still need help or is your problem solved?

Comment: OK, I'm glad you got it sorted out.